Virtual environment name echoed in VSCode terminal with Starship
I am using VSCode on a Mac with zsh. I recently installed Starship and really like the look in my terminal. However, when activating a virtual environment, such as with pipenv, the terminal echos the venv name instead of just writing a blank line.
Expected behavior

test on  master via  v3.11.6 (test) 
❯ 

test on  master via  v3.11.6 (test) 
❯ 

Actual behavior
test
test on  master via  v3.11.6 (test) 
❯ 
test
test on  master via  v3.11.6 (test) 
❯ 

How can I disable this? It's only occurring in the VSCode terminal and only in a virtual environment.

This only happens when the venv is automatically activated in the terminal. Disabling that feature prevents the name from being echoed once it is manually activated.

See Where is the setting to remove the name of the venv from VS Code's terminal prompt?

Set the POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_PROMPT environment variable to modify the prompt, per the Poetry documentation. I remove it, I replaced it with a space in .zshrc.
POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_PROMPT=" "

